# Is the image of gradient map from Sobolev space to Lebesgue space weakly closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-derivatives

Suppose f is a map defined between $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $L^{p'}(\Omega)$ as follows - $u \mapsto |\nabla u|^{p-1}$. Is the range of this map weakly closed in $L^{p'}$?.

Comment: $p'$ being the conjugate of $p$.